# Using bind to force the context of a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm working on a bit of JavaScript code that will be used to build constructors for "classes" (specifically View Models) for our enterprise-level software. One of the things that I'm doing is establishing a code-enforced design pattern, where the implementer will explicitly define what functions they want exposed by the instance of the class, and the code will add them to the `prototype` of the constructor, as opposed to properties of each instance of the class. This of course has the advantage of there only being one instance of each of these functions per type, as opposed to an instance for every instance.

[Here's a CodePen of most of my examples.](http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/ByQBmx)

The problem is that under certain conditions, I am dealing with [binding loss](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations) issues. For example, with this constructor:

```
  function Foo(myName) {
    this.firstName = myName;
  }

  Foo.prototype.greet = function(yourName) {
    alert("Hello, " + yourName + ". I am " + this.firstName + ".");
  }
```

...this will work:

```
var sam = new Foo("Sam");
// Alerts "Hello, Denny. I am Sam."
sam.greet("Denny");
```

...but this will not:

```
var sad = new Foo("Sad");
// This changes the context of greet. :(
var sadGreet = sad.greet;
// Alerts "Hello, Denny. I am undefined."
sadGreet("Denny");
```

This is because when we do `var sadGreet = sad.greet` we are changing the context of the `greet` function to `window`, so `this.firstName` does not exist when calling `sadGreet("Denny")`.

So, a solution that I came up with was to overwrite the prototype with a property that calls that prototype, wrapping it in [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function Bar(myName) {
  this.firstName = myName;
  // Here's where the magic happens.
  this.greet = Bar.prototype.greet.bind(this);
}

Bar.prototype.greet = function(yourName) {
  alert("Hello, " + yourName + ". I am " + this.firstName + ".");
}

var happy = new Bar("Happy");
// Since each instance of Bar overwrites the context for greet, this will work. :)
var happyGreet = happy.greet;
// Alerts "Hello, Denny. I am Happy."
happyGreet("Denny");
```

**My question is this:** I assume that `Bar` is not quite as efficient as `Foo`, but does this completely void any benefit of declaring `greet` as a `prototype` method? Under the covers is it just duplicating `greet` as a property, anyway, or is my call to `bind` simply adding a "wrapper" for `Bar.prototype.greet`? In other words, is this effectively exactly the same as the above definition for Bar?

```
function Bar(myName) {
  this.firstName = myName;
  // Here's where the magic happens.
  this.greet = function(yourName) {
    alert("Hello, " + yourName + ". I am " + this.firstName + ".");
  }
}
```

Bonus points if you can not only answer the question but tell me how to test it!

Comment: Questions about efficiency are usually tough for SO because it's hard to answer conclusively. That said, my primary reaction is that I'd consider `happyGreet(...)` in general to be a mistake. If a function is on an instance, you probably shouldn't go assigning it to a variable, if if you do, you should `.bind` it there at the assignment location, or do `happyGreet.call(happy, "Denny")`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for your response, and I agree. Unfortunately this is only one of several possible examples of how "binding loss" can occur - and I'm not necessarily in control of every implementation of these constructors.

Comment: A function's execution context includes a *this* parameter that is set **by how the function is called**, or using *bind*. If you change how you call a function, they you will likely change its *this*. Or not.

Comment: What are your criteria for efficient? Use less memory? Run faster? Require less code? How *bind* works is defined in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5) so you can answer some of the questions yourself.

Comment: @RobG: Defining a `prototype` function means you only have one instance of that function in existence at a time, not one instance of that function for every instance of that class. What I want to know is, does using `bind` the way I have in `Bar` effectively duplicate the function for each instance, or is it only duplicating a wrapper function that then calls  `prototype.greet`?

Comment: @Grinn according to the MDN specs, bind creates a new function object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Therefore, each instance will have a new greet function. Each new greet function is a wrapper that calls prototype.greet, but that doesn't eliminate the fact that memory was allocated to create the new greet functions for each instance.

Comment: @wmock—ECMA-262 defines behaviour, not implementation, so whether the function object is actually copied or just appears to be copied is moot and probably has very little effect on performance. A bigger question is why this strategy would be used at all. Why are programmers allowed to determine the methods that an object will have on the fly? Why hasn't the architect already determined the structure of objects and the methods they require? An object with an unused method on its `[[Prototype]]` has used zero additional memory and suffered no performance loss. So what's the point? :-/

Comment: @RobG I'm honestly not too sure about the implementation details but according to MDN and my own testing, the 'this.greet = Bar.prototype.greet.bind(this)' function is definitely different from the Bar.prototype.greet function. A simple triple equality test shows that they are indeed different function objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bar is definitely less efficient than Foo but not in terms of time complexity. Instead, it's less efficient in terms of memory consumption since each instance of Bar will now have a UNIQUE and NEW 'greet' function object (the 'bind' function creates a new function object).

Looking at your code, it actually becomes slightly convoluted to even have the 'greet' function on Bar.prototype. Instead, this works as well:

```
function Bar(myName) {
  this.firstName = myName;
  this.greet = greet.bind(this);
}

var greet = function(yourName) {
  alert("Hello, " + yourName + ". I am " + this.firstName + ".");
};

var happy = new Bar("Happy");
var happyGreet = happy.greet;
happyGreet("Denny");
```

You can test that the 'greet' function is not identical to each instance's 'greet' function by simply trying this:

```
console.log( greet === happyGreet );
```

Comment: In your example, wouldn't `happy.greet` also be a UNIQUE and NEW `greet` function as well?

Comment: No, happy.greet is simply a REFERENCE to the 'greet' function object that belongs to each instance of Bar. Basically the 'var greet' function is one function, and then each instance of Bar creates a new 'greet' function based off of the 'var greet' function.

Comment: Edited my response to show that greet is not the same function as happyGreet. This also works the same in your previous example: happyGreet !== Bar.prototype.greet

Comment: So is this effectively the same as `this.greet = function (yourName) { greet.call(this, yourName); };` (where only that small, anonymous function would be replicated) or will using `bind` cause it to duplicate the entire `greet` function?

Comment: Yes, they are effectively the same since you're creating a new function that is using 'call' to execute the original 'greet' function. In both cases, memory will be allocated to create new greet functions for each instance and each of these new greet functions implicitly call the original 'greet' function (either via bind or call).

Comment: Hmm... I guess any way you look at it, you'll have to allocate memory for that distinct context. Does this seem to you to be the most efficient means of doing what I want, or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you'd want to take care of the different cases on how the original Bar.prototype.greet function is invoked. I understand that you would love the 'this' binding once you do something like 'var happyGreet = happy.greet' but in those cases, I would then just create a one-off function with bind or call to fix the 'this' binding.